# c++ Partial template specialization with typename as void

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing something about `Partial template specialization`.What I want to do is that using a template `is_valid` to check if the class has a member type named `valid`. The source code is as below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    typedef void valid;
};

class B {
public:
    typedef int valid;
};

class C {
};

template <typename T, typename U = void> struct is_valid
{
    const static bool value = false;
};

template <typename T> struct is_valid<T, typename T::valid>
{
    const static bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_valid<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_valid<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_valid<C>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output is

```
1
0
0
```

The last `0` is clear because `C` class has no member. But why is in `B` case, the output is 0?

Can anyone help me to understand what is the mechanism of `Partial template specialization` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `is_valid<B>`, the primary template is found, since the 2nd template argument is not specified, the default value `void` is used, the instantiation is supposed to be `is_valid<B, void>`. Then specializations get checked. The problem is `B::valid` is of type `int`, the instantiation got from specialization would be `is_valid<B, int>`, which doesn't match the instantiation from the primary template; so the partial specialization won't be selected, the primary template is selected instead.

For `is_valid<A>`, same as above, the instantiation got from primary template is `is_valid<A, void>`. Since `A::valid` is of type `void`, the partial specialization gives instantiation as `is_valid<A, void>` too. The specialization is preferred and selected.

If you specify the 2nd template argument as `int` like `is_valid<B, int>`, the partial specialization will be selected.

If you just want to check whether the member type `valid` exists or not, you can use `std::void_t` which always yielding type `void` in the partial specialization.

```
template <typename T> struct is_valid<T, std::void_t<typename T::valid>> 
{
    const static bool value = true;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WNnL7XXnCImD7IaR)

Comment: Hi, songyuanyao. I am confused about why `is_valid<A, void>` would match the second template but not the primary one since the primary template can also accept void argument.

Comment: Sorry, to make my question clear, I want to know, in which case the second template would be selected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @irasin Specialization is preferred over primary template; that's why specialization exists. More precisely, if all are usable, explicit specialization is preferred over partial specialization, which is perferred over primary template.

Comment: The problem is B::valid is of type int, the instantiation got from specialization would be is_valid<B, int>, which doesn't match the instantiation from the primary template; Did you mean that only if the case of `is_valid<B, void>` can match the primary template? I think `template <typename T, typename U = void> struct is_valid` can match any type of `is_valid<T, anytype>`.  It seems there is something wrong here.

Comment: @irasin But you didn't specify the 2nd template argument, just write `is_vaid<B>`, then the default value `void` is appied as `is_valid<B, void>`, then the 2nd template parameter must be `void` when checking specializations. As I said, if you write it as `is_valid<B, int>`, the partial specialization will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename _T>
struct have_member_valid
{
    template<typename T> static std::true_type check(decltype(&T::valid)*);
    template<typename T> static std::false_type check(...);

public:
    constexpr static bool value = decltype(check<_T>(0))::value;
};
```

Here is another example to tell whether a class member exists, but I don't quite sure how it works. Maybe param (...) has the lowest priority to match?

Refer: [Templated check for the existence of a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function)
(modified a little)